# /usr/bin/ruby file just contains gibberish and the word 'ELF'; safe to delete this/is this the file I really need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filesystems, corruption, bin

I'm trying to install the Ruby gem `foreverb`, to keep my server process running when SSH disconnects, and also for improved understanding of the people visiting my site.

On following this guide:

https://github.com/DAddYE/foreverb

It mentioned to write some code in `/usr/bin/ruby` so I dutifully opened the file and looked inside. Instead of what I expected (either a blank file or something that looks like Ruby code) I was instead greeted with this:

```
^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@>^@^A^@^@^@à^H^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^Q^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@8^@        ^@@^@^[^@^Z^@^F^@^@^@^E^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ø^A^@^@^@^@^@^@ø^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@8^B^@^@^@^@^@^@8^B^@^@^@^@^@^@8^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^\^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^\^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@¼^K^@^@^@^@^@^@¼^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^F^@^@^@ ^M^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^M ^@^@^@^@^@ ^M ^@^@^@^@^@p^B^@^@^@^@^@^@x^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^F^@^@^@¸^M^@^@^@^@^@^@¸^M ^@^@^@^@^@¸^M ^@^@^@^@^@Ð^A^@^@^@^@^@^@Ð^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^D^@^@^@T^B^@^@^@^@^@^@T^B^@^@^@^@^@^@T^B^@^@^@^@^@^@D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Påtd^D^@^@^@<98>
^@^@^@^@^@^@<98>
^@^@^@^@^@^@<98>
```

Not entirely sure what it is, but pretty sure it shouldn't be there. Is it file corruption, as it doesn't look like what I'd generally consider to be file corruption? While I assume it's probably not doing anything useful at the moment, does the presence of semi-arbirary strings in this file represent a problem with my Ruby installation which I need to fix? Is there perhaps another location or set of locations where the right file might be, and perhaps this one isn't being used?

I notice I have a lot of problems with my server, and often find I have to randomly reinstall gems which seem to disappear from my system, usually after the SSH disconnects. Could this file be something to do with that?

It seems odd to me that if this is the location of an important Ruby system file that my Ruby installation should work at all, but it does seem to... Might it be left over from a previously broken installation? I'm only just progressing out of the beginner stages with Ruby, so any insight into what the file does, why it's important and, particularly, how I should progress would be extremely helpful. Also, any suggestions for further reading on Ruby framework eco system which might help me better understand the inner working of stuff like this would hopefully save me from having to take up people's time here with similar questions in the future, though I understand that's a little outside the usual remit for the site.

Comment: One thing I'm thinking is that it looks a bit like a regular expression? But how would something like that get inside my Ruby file?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ruby` is a binary file, it's not meant for human consumption. This guide does not tell you to edit the file, but to put `#!/usr/bin/ruby` on top of your something.rb file...

Comment: The guide says: "Place your script under your standard directory, generally on my env is bin or scripts.

In that case is: bin/foo" I assumed `bin/ruby` was the file meant. What is meant by 'your standard directory'? Do you know?

Comment: This is a directory of your choice, where else do you keep the scripts that run regularly on your server? I have a `bin` directory in my home folder where I keep this stuff.

Comment: Oh, I see. It means the bin directory within my project directory. Which contains scripts instead of binaries. Gotcha :).

Comment: this file is basically ruby itself, and you definitely don't want to edit this